# How to point Java to a symbolic link

Tags: java, linux, unix, solaris

Let's say I have symbolic link called /home/team/Java , I want to point Java to that symbolic link

How can I do it Solaris?

Expectation :

When I type "which java" in my environment

It should give output "home/team/Java"

Comment: Put that link on the `$PATH`?

Comment: Sorry Andy I didn't get your question

Comment: `which` uses the `PATH` environment variable to resolve binaries. Put you symlink into that.

Comment: How can I edit the PATH environment ? Please suggest for Solaris environment. Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```
ln -s /usr/bin/j2re1.4.2_17/bin/java home/team/Java
```

here /usr/bin/j2re1.4.2_17/bin/java is your actual java installation directory path